# First call to ReactContext is setting the isLoading sate to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-context

I have **Component A** and **Component B** that both uses the same ReactContext to fetch the data. Whichever component calls the context first, at the end of fetching the data, the Context sets the **isFetchingData** state to **false**.

Now, when the second component calls the context the isFetchingData state is already set to false. Therefore, it renders the component without waiting for the data.

**To illustrate:**

ComponentA => isFetchingData? true => getsData => sets isFetchingData to false. => **renders component**

ComponentB => isFetchingData? false => **renders the component** => getsData => sets isFetchingData to false (already false)

How can I address this?

Following is my code.

**Context:**

```
    const [allEmployees, setAllEmployees] = useState([]);
    const [isFetchingData, setIsFetchingData] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllEmployees().then(
            //doing something
        ).then(employees => {
            setAllEmployees();
            setIsFetchingData(false);
        });
    }, [])
```

**Component:**

```
const ComponentB = () => {

    const {
        allEmployees,
        isFetchingData
    } = useContext(MyContext);


    if(isFetchingData) {
        return <p>'Loading'</p>; // it never hits this as its false
    }

    return (
    // if data is loaded render this
    );
};
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to provide more of the code to have a clue about what could be going on here. Enough code to be able to see (for, instance) whether component A and B are children of the same provider component; what values does the context expose etc.