# Not awaiting for data in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a useEffect in my component that is waiting for data from the context so that it can set it in state. But its not waiting for the state and is moving on to the next line of code to set isLoading to false.

I'd like it to wait for the data so that I can render the loading.

I tried setting the isFetchingData in the context but I had run into problems where if another component calls it first it would set the isFetchingData state to false.

[First call to ReactContext is setting the isLoading sate to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462393/first-call-to-reactcontext-is-setting-the-isloading-sate-to-false)

It is fine for results to come back with no records. The component would render 'No records found'. Therefore, I cannot check the length on state to say if  length is zero then keep loading.

Following is my code:

**Context**

```
    const [activeEmployees, setActiveEmployees] = useState([]);
    const [terminatedEmployees, setTerminatedEmployees] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

            getEmployees()
                .then(response => {
                    /// some code...
                    setActiveEmployees(response.activeEmployees)
                    setTerminatedEmployees(response.terminatedEmployees)
                });

    });
```

**Component**

```
const EmployeesTab = () => {

    const { activeEmployees, terminatedEmployees } = useContext(BlipContext);


    //Component states
    const [isFetchingData, setIsFetchingData] = useState(true);

    const [newEmployees, setNewEmployees] = useState([]);
    const [oldEmployees, setOldEmployees] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            await setNewEmployees(activeEmployees);
            await setOldEmployees(terminatedEmployees);
            setIsFetchingData(false);
        }
        getData();
    }, [activeEmployees, terminatedEmployees, isFetchingData]);


    if(isFetchingData) {
        return <p>'Loading'</p>;
    }

    return (
    // if data is loaded render this
    );
};

export default EmployeesTab;
```

Comment: The context must set the isFetchingData flag, now you're just await:ing the useState methods that have nothing to do with the data retrieval. Or just check if the data exists.

Comment: @GuyIncognito thanks for your comments. I tried that approach but I had multiple components calling context and it would set isFetchingData to false. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462393/first-call-to-reactcontext-is-setting-the-isloading-sate-to-false

Comment: Well if the result can be an empty array, why are you using an empty array as the default state? `useState(null)` initially and check for null. Although I can't see why multiple components would make any difference.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Sorry for not clarifying.. multuple components would make a difference because it is a ReactContext. So if one component calls it. The state will have records already. After performing some actions, I want to re-fetch fresh data when the second component calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `useState` inside your `useContext`, I don't see the point of storing yet again the `activeEmployees` in another state.

If you want to have a local loading variable it could something like:

```js
const loading = !(activeEmployees.length && terminatedEmployees.length);
```

This `loading` will update whenever `getEmployees` changes.

And to answer you question, the reason `await` is not having an effect is because `setState` is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only problem with that is it is fine to have zero records returned. It would render as 'No records found'. Otherwise, it will be loading infinitely,

Comment: I see, so if you have an empty state and a loading state you need a loading variable to track that, I would add it to the context, before `getEmployees` set loading to true, and when fulfilled set to false. Even if someone else calls that context the loading will be ok.

Comment: I tried the approach of adding it to the context but I hit the issue of not able to reset the loading state to its intial state of true. Please have a look at this as this is what I tried first... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462393/first-call-to-reactcontext-is-setting-the-isloading-sate-to-false?noredirect=1#comment113989331_64462393

Comment: Have a look at this sample https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-chebyshev-n0df5